# The recently deleted questions page shows that there's an answer to my question but I don't see it

Tags: bug, status-declined, deleted-questions

I see no answer at https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/35943, but the question list indicates 1?

[image: Screenshot of the "Recently deleted questions" page]

https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/35964, https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/35949, https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/35796

Answer (score 4):

There is a deleted answer there, which was deleted before the question was deleted, so you can't see it as you can only see deleted answers that were deleted at the same time the question was.

I've retagged this as a bug because it seems like we should make sure the number on the recently deleted questions page matches what you can actually see to avoid situations like this.

Thanks for bringing it to meta so we can look into it!

Answer (score 2):

We are not going to be fixing this. The display uses a saved `AnswerCount` value that is saved with the question record. We do not calculate this on the fly, and do so here (and in other places in the system that exhibit the same issue) will add too high of a performance cost, which we are deciding not to incur to fix this relatively rare edge case.